# How does a windows service behaves on Windows shutdown?

Tags: c#, windows, service, timeout, shutdown

Is there a timeout for stopping Windows Services when Windows is shutting down? I know there is a registry key "WaitToKillServiceTimeout" but does this timeout effect on services, when Windows is shutting down or is there another timeout?

I want to find out, how long system during shutdown waits for services when it calls the OnStop method of a service.

Can a service prevent Windows from shutting down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976045.aspx):

> [WaitToKillServiceTimeout] Determines how long the system waits for services to stop after notifying the service that the system is shutting down.

Then yes, that's value used to wait for services shutdown but also note that it's shared for all services:

> If all services stop before this value expires, the system shuts down...

For your question *"Can a service prevent Windows from shutting down?"* answer is "more or less". You can't prevent Windows to shutdown (it may be really annoying for users if they can't shutdown because a service decided they shouldn't) but:

> When the value of this entry expires, the system notifies the user that the service has not stopped. The user can either force the service task to stop or continue to wait. If the user waits, this value specifies the interval between repeated user notices that the service has not stopped.

Note that:

> Some services increase the value of this entry to provide more time for cleanup tasks.

In case your service is slow to shutdown you may increase such value (during installation) to give you more time. In theory using a very high value you'll *postpone* shutdown for a very long time (but this behavior isn't same as *cancel* it and don't forget it's shared for all services).

AFAIK a service can't *cancel* shutdown but a GUI application can do it using [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376877%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer;)

Comment: Does ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime() override the [WaitToKillServiceTimeout] or doesn't it?

Comment: @Mi.Sharp it does but it doesn't cancel shutdown, it postpones it. Moreover OnStop() is executed in a working thread and if your service hangs (because shutdown lock resources) service may not update checkpoints and SCM will decide it hanged (terminating it).

Comment: In short: if you just need more time you can call RequestAdditionalTime() waiting for another working thread to finish (users will see Windows is shutting down and it takes long time) but if your target is to cancel shutdown (UI will be responsive and shutdown won't occur) then you have to cancel it (with a small hidden GUI application that communicates with your service).

Comment: I'm not sure that article is entirely correct; I don't think the system notifies the user when the timeout expires, it just continues with the shutdown.  (In the old days, when a shutdown didn't necessarily turn off the power, services could actually continue to run *after* shutdown, though obviously what they could do in that state was fairly limited.)